# Ошибка в django Requested setting DATABASES, but settings are not configured

Tags: python, django

Появляется ошибка при запуске теста django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DATABASES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

## test_logic.py

````
from store.logic import operations


```class LogicTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_plus(self):
        result = operations(6, 13, '+')
        self.assertEqual(19, result)``` 
# logic.py
```def operations(a, b, c):
  if c == '+':
        return a + b
    if c == '-':
        return a - b
    if c == '*':
        return a * b```

Помогите уже день не могу исправить эту ошибку. Искал в интернете, но не помогло. [![весь проект][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjQP9.png
````

Comment: откуда это запускается? это вообще частью джанго проекта является?

Comment: да это часть проекта джанго. Вот сам проект https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjQP9.png